# How to set up and down not so much blank screen? I was used Chewie plugin

Tags: flutter

How to set up and down not so much blank screen?
I used Chewie plugin

[image]

Comment: share some code snippet plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried to used

```
SizedBox(
                              height: 250,
                              child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController!),
                            )
```